# Get to the Application from astatic class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get to the application from my static class but get this error

> The method getActivity() is undefined for the type PniemActivity.MyFragmentAdapter

But when i leave getActivity() out i get this message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplication() from the type Activity

This is my code.

```
private static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private final int NUM_OF_PAGES = 10;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index){
        return PageFragment.newInstance("Hoi "+ index );

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
    appData = ((myApp) getActivity().getApplication()).slaughterData;

        return NUM_OF_PAGES;


    }


}
```

I want to get the amount of fragments needed from my database and that is why i want to get access to my application.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Extends Application class, define in AndroidManifest, implement singleton pattern onto your Application class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell getActivity() is a method on Fragment, not on FragmentPageAdapter. [You could get the current Fragment from the FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) (which you have a reference to), but I would probably do as Vladimir suggests in the comment:

1. Add your class that extends Application to your AndroidManifest:
2. Implement a singleton pattern (with a getInstance method) or simply add a public static reference to your Application subclass

Answer (score 1):

If get count from DB is the only one reason to do that just query your DB from getCount() method.

If you really want to get activity by static field (**this is BAD in general**):
Activity:

```
public static MyActivity instance;

onCreate(){
  instance = this;

}
```

Anywhere in your app:

```
MyActivity instance = MyActivity.instance;
```

Using this solution you are about getting into troubles, so be warned. I works in Java, but there is no guarantee how it works with Android.